# is it possible to make one js file for multiple html pages

Tags: javascript

I am making a small registration form making separate pages for login and signup
so is there any way we can make one js file for both when I am trying to do it gives me the error "cannot read properties of null event listener".

My js Code

```
const loginbtn = document.getElementById("login1-btn");
loginbtn.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    // e.preventDefault()
    console.log("test")
})

const registerbtn = document.getElementById("register-btn");

const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const username = document.getElementById("username");
    const email = document.getElementById("r-email");
    const password = document.getElementById("password");
    const phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");

    console.log("testing register")
    const auth = getAuth();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.value, password.value)
        .then((user credentials) => {
            const user = user credential.user;
            console.log(user)

            // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage)
            // ..
        });
}


registerbtn.addEventListener("click", register)
```

My html Code for login

```
<div class="row row-input ">
                    <div class="input-field col s12  l11">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                        <input id="l-email" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="l-email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-input">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 l11">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                        <input id="l-password" type="password" class="validate">
                        <label for="l-password">Password</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row center-align">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light login-btn" id="login1-btn">Log In
                        <i class="material-icons right ">send</i>
                    </button>
```

My html Code For Signup

```
     <div class="row row-input ">
                        <div class="input-field col s12  l12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                            <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row row-input ">
                        <div class="input-field col s6  l6">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                            <input id="r-email" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="r-email">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6 l6">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                            <input id="phoneNumber" type="tel" class="validate">
                            <label for="phoneNumber">Telephone</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row row-input">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 l12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row row-input">
                        <div class="file-field input-field col l12 s12">
                            <div class="btn">
                                <span>Picture</span>
                                <input type="file">
                            </div>
                            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row center-align">
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light login-btn" type="submit" name="action" id="register-btn">Register
                            <i class="material-icons right ">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Is it possible to create a single page? Also, recommend to me what is a good way of making a registration form.
Thanks!

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: @Sarah check again

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element is found. If you run the code on a page that doesn't have the login button, you won't get an error.

```
const loginbtn = document.getElementById("login1-btn");
if (loginbtn) {
    loginbtn.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
        // e.preventDefault()
        console.log("test")
    })
}
```